# Working with a PSObject

Tags: powershell

I have the below code which is designed to add event log warning/errors from the System log to an existing HTML table structure. However, I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
$eventLogArray = @()
$eventLogs = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -LogName System -EntryType Error,Warning -Newest 50
ForEach ($log in $eventLogs) {
    $item = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    TimeGenerated = $log.TimeGenerated
    Entry = $log.EntryType
    ID = $log.EventID
    Source = $log.Source
    Message = $log.Message
    }
    $eventLogArray += $item 
}


ForEach($event in $eventLogArray) {
    $body += @"
    <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <td>$event</td> 
    </tr>       
"@
```

Each `$event` contains the correct entry from the array `$eventLogArray` but when it carries out the `$body +=` it fails but without any error, my table just contains no event log entries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting $eventLogArray as an HTML table:

```
($eventLogArray | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment) -match '^<tr>'
```

Comment: I can't use ConvertTo-HTML becasue the above is going to a table within another table that can be collapsed.

Comment: I believe you need to use the -Fragment switch for that.

Comment: No, it can't have the beginning <table> statement

Comment: If you just need the table rows, you can strip those out using -match.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having problems understanding what you want to do. `$event` is a psobject, so when it's referenced directly in the here-string(and not a property of the object), your result body would look like:

```
<tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <td>@{TimeGenerated=10/24/2013 22:52:19; Entry=Error; ID=36887; Source=Schannel; Message=A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoin
t. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.}</td> 
</tr>
```

Is that what you want?

You could also simplify and speed up your code with pipelines and replace the first foreach-loop with `select-object`. The output above was generated using the code below, so it is working.

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -LogName System -EntryType Error,Warning -Newest 50 | 
Select-Object TimeGenerated, @{name="Entry";expression={$_.EntryType}}, @{name="ID";expression={$_.EventID}}, Source, Message | 
ForEach-Object {
    $body += @"
    <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <td>$_</td> 
    </tr>       
"@
}
```

Comment: How exxactly does this work: @{name="Entry";expression={$_.EntryType}} ?

Comment: `Select-object` can accept a hashtable to define a custom property. the hashtable uses a name/label property for the property name, and an expression for the code to calculate the custom property's value. So I created ex. one custom property `ID` where the value is equal to the objects `EventID` property

Comment: I would also use the Select-Object approach.  It does what your foreach over $eventLogs does but in a more canonical PowerShell way.  It behaves like SQL select, picking off only the properties you are interested in (and allowing you to create new ones as well using hashtables).  FWIW, I couldn't repro the problem.  $body has the same data in in that @Graimer is seeing. I'm running PowerShell V4.